# Are my criticisms of the way one asks a question valid?

Tags: discussion

I criticized the way a member ask [his question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/63620/what-doesas-lately-as-mean) for addressing the answerers. He used to begin with *everybody* or *as a educated and native speaker*. In my opinion not only they are impolite but they ignore part of potential answerers.

But on the other hand, I think he is too polite in the rest of the question I addressed. Should one use *could you please* in every other sentence of his question? 
What are the norms of posting a question in the network.

Comment: I think I've edited those out of nima's questions something like 40-50 times.

Comment: @snailboat - I wish nima would learn from other people's edits. I don't mind doing those touch-ups for new users who are learning the ropes, but these users should eventually catch on and start improving their own work.

Comment: @J.R. That's why I try to leave a comment in those cases explaining proper etiquette on the site. The one I use most often is when the title is too generic. It may not get them to change their behavior but it's more direct than simply removing the bad content.

Comment: @Catija I've left comments a number of times when people have asked for answers from native speakers, for example [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/4332/#comment5906_4332) and [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/21049/#comment39458_21049) and [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/43066/#comment80193_43066) and [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/24452/#comment46200_24452).  I can express my point of view, but I can't make people listen.

Comment: @snailboat of course not. I said that, too. Just pointing out that *only* fixing the text is likely aided by a note.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, we [really don't want "native speakers only" banners](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/904/requests-for-native-speakers-to-answer-questions), as you've probably seen. Those should be edited out by anyone who sees them.

As far as excessive politeness, the [network standard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/3021#3021) is to edit out most phatic expressions/needless verbiage/noise/static/fluff/whatever you want to call it. ELL [sticks to that](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1367/how-helpful-is-it-to-add-hope-this-is-helpful-to-an-ell-answer/). Posts should be as brief as practical, and not waste time with pleasantries.

On that particular question, I trimmed out about half the fluff; I could have rephrased "would you possibly show me" to be shorter but nothing came immediately to mind, so I left it.